# Getting VB to enable Delivery and Read reciepts in MS Outlook Emails

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm using Interop for sending e-mails via Outlook, but I am not able to specify or enable delivery receipts and read receipts.

I have searched all over the web to try to see if this is possible but so far have come up with nothing in terms of manipulating Outlook to enable these options in the emails my code produces.

Code:

```
Dim body As String
Dim objOutlook, objEmail
objOutlook = CType(CreateObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
body = "Dear Recipient..."
With objEmail
    .Subject = "Subject..."
    .To = EmailAddresses()
    .Body = body
    '.Attachments.Add(sFilename)
    .Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh
    '
    '.**PROPERTIES TO SET DELIVERY AND READ RECEIPTS???**
    '
    'Show on screen
    .Display(True)
    'Uncomment the below to actually send the email
    '.Send()
End With
```

My emails work just fine, but I want to enable the read and delivery receipt options.  Anybody know how to do this?  From what I can tell, it may involve something to do with the **_MailItem.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested** Property, but I'm not quite sure how to use it properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `MailItem.ReadReceiptRequested` and `MailItem.OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested` properties to true.